# activityButton.setOnClickListener in android studio

Tags: android

I really really hate to post this because I have seen sooooo many similar post but I have sincerely gone through post after post...google search after google search and nothing really seems to answer my question. Please excuse my ignorance.

I'm going through a Sams Teach yourself android application development book and they have this sample, in which similar sample code is on developer.android.com but for some reason android studio is giving me a fit about this code. Mind you I know nothing about application development so I'm really trying to learn and asking for help.

The objective is to create a main activity that will invoke a second activity via a button in the main activity.

This is what I have

```
package com.example.owner.hour2application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
Button activityButton =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button) ;
activityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
    {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondaryActivity.class);
        startActivity(startIntent);
            }
      });

}
}
```

and Android studio is fussing about cannot resolve symbol setOnClickListener AND cannot resolve view and the unexpected token ")" after the bracket.

PLEASE HELP!!! Thank you sooo much in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many brackets in your code. This is what it should look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button activityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
        activityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
                startActivity(startIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So now I have more questions about this code I am getting this error Method invocation 'activityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View... may produce java.lang.NullPointerException what does that mean???